# Counting RGBA values with Python

Tags: python, count, rgba

I read an image, shoved the RGBA values into an array and now I want to count the occurence of certain colors. However all I'm getting is 0. How do I do that (without converting to string)? Relevant code snippets and output:

Output:

```
Image123.png
8820
[(138, 18, 20, 255), (138, 18, 20, 255), (138, 18, 20, 255), (138, 18, 20, 255), (138, 18, 20, 255), (138, 18, 20, 255), (138, 18, 20, 255), (138, 18, 20, 255), (138, 18, 20, 255), (138, 18, 20, 255), (138, 18, 20, 255), (138, 18, 20, 255), (138, 18, 20, 255), (138, 18, 20, 255), (138, 18, 20, 255), (138, 18, 20, 255), (138, 18, 20, 255), (138, 18, 20, 255), (138, 18, 20, 255), ......
0
0
```

Code:

```
read_pixel = []

print(filename)
read_pixel.append(pixel[image_x, image_y])

print(image_size_x*image_size_y)
print(read_pixel)

count_lte_70_1 = read_pixel.count("(138, 18, 20, 255)")
print(count_lte_70_1)

#without parenthesis
count_lte_70_2 = read_pixel.count("138, 18, 20, 255")
print(count_lte_70_2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes are your problem here, you're searching for a tuple and not a string. Just leave the quotes and use

```
read_pixel.count((138, 18, 20, 255))
```

Answer (score 2):

With

```
count_lte_70_1 = read_pixel.count("(138, 18, 20, 255)")
```

you're searching for occurrences of a **string**, while your list contains **tuples**. Instead, you should use:

```
count_lte_70_1 = read_pixel.count((138, 18, 20, 255))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you shouldn't use `count("(a,b,c,d)")` but `count((a,b,c,d))`

The way you are doing it now counts the number of Strings in the List

```
x=[(1,2),(3,4),(3,4)]
print(x.count((1,2)) #returns 1
print(x.count((3,4)) #returns 2
```